# How do I prevent Resharper's error in solution window from showing CSS/javascript errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I love Resharper's solution analysis tool. It has served me very well in a lot of desktop and server applications. Now I need to do some web development. I want to use Resharper for the C# code, but Javascript/Html/Css errors appear in the list as well. ALT-SHIFT-PageDown sends me to these errors all the time.

In our team, someone else is in charge of the front-end. I don't even have the skill to judge of the quality of their code. All I want is to exclude all errors that are not C# so I can concentrate on my back-end code. Is this or some other workaround possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can try adding a file mask in your ignored list.

Resharper -> Options -> Code Inspection Settings -> Edit Items To Skip

Add `.css` and `.js`. This won't help with inline CSS/JS, but it will exclude the external files.

Or go to Inspection Severity and set "Do Not Show" under all options in the JS/CSS/HTML tabs.

Comment: When I exclude the css, js, etc. files, they show the grey "not analysed" icon and there is no underlining in the file so I first thought it had worked, but they still show up in the "Errors in solution" window and ALT-SHIFT-PageDown still navigates to them. Is this controlled through another setting or is this a bug? I am using V6.1.37.86.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Errors in Solution" window, you can batch-select all *.js and *.css files that you don't want to be inspected, by right-clicking and choosing "Ignore Errors".

Comment: It works, but I have to do this every time I receive updates from the front end guys. I hoped for an automated way of doing this. I thought Brandon had found it, but for some reason, excluding the files doesn't work...

Comment: Agreed: there could be a better way to do this. On another note, aren't your front end guys using static code analysis?

Comment: I am pretty sure they don't. They don't even have Resharper in their setup. It could be a good thing to bring them there, but I am in no position to guide them. I have no skill nor interest in front end technologies.